# how to add specific character or symbol between string?

Tags: php, string, function, symbols

i am to add specific symbol in string just like

string is "12555.12000000" then output is 12,555.12

which php function help me to display this type of output

```
 $cartTotal ="12555.120000000";
```

Comment: you could have just googled it and have the solution much easier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are looking for the [number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) function in PHP, Which can be used like this:

```
$cartTotal = number_format(12555.120000000, 2, '.', ',');
```

The function takes 4 parameters:

- number - The number you wish to format
- decimal places - the number of decimal places to show
- decimal point character - in this case: .
- thousands separator - in this case: ,

and returns the formatted string.

**EDIT** - There are plenty of other [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=format+numbers+in+php) to this question already